# Chaining multiple constructors

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I understand that when chaining constructors this must be done on the first line of the main constructor, can someone explain how you would go about the below code.
I want to chain to all constructors so that they can all be private other than the main constructor.

```
public class Flight {

    int passengers = 0;
    int seats  = 150;
    double maxKgPerPassenger;

    private Flight(int passengers) {
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }

    private Flight(int seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    private Flight(double maxKgPerPassenger) {
        this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
    }

    public Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger) {
        this(passengers); 
        this(seats);
        this(maxKgPerPassenger);    
    }

}
```

Comment: you need your first 3 constructor to call the last one with default values

Comment: `private Flight(int seats){ this(20,seats, 20.0D); }`

Comment: you just pass some values you think are correct into the constructor. Plus the argument you're recieving

Answer (score 3):

A constructor is up to set as many fields as possible or construct an instance completely.

You pick a constructor which has a greater number of arguments and use it within constructors with a smaller amount. For example,

```
public Flight(double maxKgPerPassenger) {
    this(0, 0, maxKgPerPassenger); // default, default, maxKgPerPassenger
}

private Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger) {
    this.passengers = passengers; 
    this.seats = seats;
    this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
}
```

> I want to chain to all constructors so that they can all be private other than the main constructor.

I suggest the opposite way. Make all constructors you are going to use `public`, but an all-arguments constructor `private` if you won't be using that.

*The approach you tried to adopt is similar to [the builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) where each method sets a single field. You definitely need to have a look at it if a number of arguments are going to grow up.*

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to chain constructors ?
As you chain constructors, you have to specify some default values from the constructor with less argument to the invoked constructor with more arguments.

You do the reverse here :

```
public Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger){    
    this(passengers); 
    this(seats);
    this(maxKgPerPassenger);    
}
```

You indeed want to invoke from the constructor with the most argument all other constructors.
It makes no sense and it is not valid either as a constructor can invoke a single other constructor of the same class.

> I want to chain to all constructors so that they can all be private
>   other than the main constructor.

Things work in the reverse order.

The actual code doesn't seem to need constructor chaining.
This one is enough :

```
public Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger){
   this.passengers = passengers;
   this.seats = seats;
   this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
}
```

Suppose that class clients could create `Flight` instances with two flavors :

- by passing all parameters
- by passing only the `seats` parameter (remains being valued with default values)

You could so write :

```
public Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger){
   this.passengers = passengers;
   this.seats = seats;
   this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
}

public Flight(int seats){
    super(50, seats, 10); // you pass some default values for passengers and maxKgPerPassenger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the default constructor private to prevent constructor instantiation and instantiate objects using a public static method. This way you can work around the constructor restriction. To add a little confusion I converted your constructors to normal methods using the class name by adding *void* return type. Also consider if want you really want isn't the Builder pattern.

```
    public class Flight {

      private int passengers = 0;
      private int seats  = 150;
      private double maxKgPerPassenger;

      private Flight() {}

      private void Flight(int passengers)
      {
        this.passengers = passengers;
      }
      private void Flight(int seats)
      {
        this.seats = seats;
      }
      private void Flight(double maxKgPerPassenger)
      {
        this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
      }

      public static Flight create(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger)
      {
        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.Flight(passengers); 
        flight.Flight(seats);
        flight.Flight(maxKgPerPassenger);
        return flight;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i think i got it working the way i want from pointers. I'm aware this may not be practical or best practice but wanted to know how it works, see below;

Comment: <pre><code>
package Airline;
public class Flight {

int passengers = 0;
int seats  = 150;
double maxKgPerPassenger;

public Flight() {}

public Flight(int passengers, int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger)
{

 this(seats, maxKgPerPassenger);
 this.passengers = passengers;

}


private Flight(int seats, double maxKgPerPassenger)
{
 
 this(maxKgPerPassenger);
 this.seats = seats;

}

private Flight(double maxKgPerPassenger)
{
 
 this.maxKgPerPassenger = maxKgPerPassenger;
 
 
}


}
</pre></code>